# Run function only on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have JQuery functions written and they work as expected, However the function runs every time I click on any field of the form (to enter name, email , or anything, see code attached) I want the script to run only when the submit button is clicked. I am still new to JQuery and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Sorry about the long code.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
}
header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-right: 650px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 5px;
}

div#main-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 467px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 30px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div#get-justice {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
div#get-justice p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    padding: 40px 40px 4px 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
}
div#get-justice button {
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding: 20px 37px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
h3 {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    font-size: 33px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
div#first-question {
   text-align: center;
}

ul {
    columns: 2;
    background: #EFDFBC;
 text-align: -webkit-left;
}
li {
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0px 3px 37px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
input#quiz-question-one-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-one-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#oneYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#oneNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-two-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-two-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#twoYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#twoNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-three-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-three-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#threeYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}


/*label#threeYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-four-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-four-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fourYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fourYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-five-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-five-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fiveYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fiveYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.clientinfo{
 height:445px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 1px 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
}

button#start {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: -272px;
    margin-right: 68px;
}

hr {
    width: 165px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 27px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div#questionOneBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionTwoBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionThreeBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFourBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFiveBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
h1 {
    /* padding: 20px 4px 20px; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
/*
h1 {
    //background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 20px 4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
*/

h1#disclaimerHeader {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    /* padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px; */
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 20px;
}

div#disc-container {
    width: 450px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 10px 10px 14px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a#disclaimerLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*.hideHeader{
 display:none;
}*/

p#greenText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: green;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p#yellowText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p##bf2e1aText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

div#questionHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 163px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

/*div#resultHeader {
    margin-top: 163px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

div#resultHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}*/

div#resultHeader {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    width: 1170px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

div#quizResult {
    font-size: 20px;
    /* width: 650px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div#allResult {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -350px;
    margin-right: -350px;
    /* background: #EFDFBC; */
}

div#leftResult {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    width: 610px;
}

div#result {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    height: 634px;
    font-size: 24.5px;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    padding: 88px 45px 0px 70px;
    //font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr#eligibleHr {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 57px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 182px;
}

div#calenderToolSideText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    /* width: 300px; */
    margin-left: 551px;
    margin-bottom: -18px;
    margin-top: -334px;
    padding: 0px 68px 0px 0px;
}

div#rightSide {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    margin-left: 480px;
    margin-top: -659px;
    height: 634px;
    width: 800px;
}

div#rightSide h1 {

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    padding: 18px 10px 10px 10px;
}

hr#consultationHR {
    width: 595px;
    margin-right: 77px;
    margin-top: -29px;
}

div#calenderTool {
    background: blue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 330px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 148px;
}

hr#endingHR {
    width: 495px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    width: 597px;
    margin-right: 76px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

h3#shareQuiz {
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: -9px;
}

p#rightsidePara {
    margin-left: 131px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
 padding: 1px 0px 0px 20px;
}

p#rightsideParaTwo {
    margin-left: 136px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
}

h1#eligibleHeader {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    color: #bf2e1a;
}

div#images {
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-top: -85px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
p#bkrwebsite {
    margin-left: 550px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
}

h3#clientHeader {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    /* height: 400px; */
}

hr#clienFormHr {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

div#clientForm {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-left: 82px;
}


div#clientInfoBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    width: 425px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input#client-info-submit {
    display: inline-block;
    /* margin: 85px; */
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    /* border-color: #ddd; */
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#clienQuestionHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 163px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: 113px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}


input#clientName {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 10px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

input#clientEmail {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

input#clientPhone {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

div#clientNameDiv {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

div#clientEmailDiv {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

div#clientPhoneDiv {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

label#clientNameLabel {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 24px;
}

label#clientEmailLabel {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 24px;
}

label#clientPhoneLabel {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 24px;
}


.verticalLine {
    width: 2px;
    height: 570px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 591px;
    margin-top: -615px;
}


.bkr-header{
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 445px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.visible2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 165px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visible4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 195px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visibleHeader {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.page {
 display: none;
}

.page.active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
}

.green{
 color:green;
}

.yellow{
 color:yellow;
}

.red{
 color:red;
}


.questions {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 444px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.questions-header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.quiz-questions {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
 <title>Questions</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class = "quiz-questions">
 <div id="first-question" class="page active">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 1 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionOneBody">
  <h3>Questoin 1</h3>
  <ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
  </ul>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="second-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 2 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionTwoBody">
   <h3>Question 2</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-no" id="twoNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="third-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 3 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionThreeBody">
   <h3>Question 3 </h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-no" id="threeNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fourth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 4 of 5</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFourBody">
   <h3>Question 4</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-no" id="fourNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fifth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 5 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFiveBody">
   <h3>Question 5</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-no" id="fiveNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="client-info" class="page">
  <div id="clienQuestionHeader">
   <h1> Almost There </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="clientInfoBody">
   <h3 id="clientHeader">Input you contact information to see your eligibility</h3>
   <div id="clientForm">
    <label id="clientNameLabel" > Name : </label> 
    <div id="clientNameDiv">
     <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientName"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label id="clientEmailLabel"> Email: </label> 
    <div id="clientEmailDiv">
     <input type="text" name="clientemail" id="clientEmail" />
    </div>    
    <br>
    <label id="clientPhoneLabel"> Phone: </label> 
    <div id="clientPhoneDiv">
     <input type="text" name="clientphone" id="clientPhone"/>
    </div>      
    
    <br>
    <hr id="clienFormHr">
    <input type="submit" name="clientinformation" id="client-info-submit" onclick="result()"/>
    <!--<label for="client-info-submit" id="clientInfoLabel">No</label> -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  

<div class="page result">
 <div id="allResult">
  <div id="resultHeader">
   <h1> Congratulations </h1>
  </div>
  <h1 id="eligibleHeader"> You might be eligible. </h1>
  <hr id="eligibleHr">
  <div id="result">
  </div>
  <!-- Vertical Line -->
  <div class="verticalLine">
  </div>
  <!-- Vertical Line End -->
  <div id="rightSide">
   <h1>Schedule your free consultation now.</h1>
   <hr id="consultationHR">
   <div id="calenderTool">
   </div>
   <div id="calenderToolSideText">
    <p>Use this calender to schedule your appointment,
    or call our office to have someone do it for you.
    </p>
    <p>Because you pre-qualify, the consultation is free.</p>
    <br>
    <p>(317) 571-3600</p>
    <p>M - F, 8:30 am - 5:00 pm </p> 
   </div>
   <hr id="endingHR">
   <h3 id="shareQuiz"> Share the quiz </h3>
   <p id="rightsidePara"> Your friends won't see your results,</p>
   <p id="rightsideParaTwo">just alink to take it themselves. </p>
   <div id="images">
    <img id ="facebook" src="logos/FacebookIcon.png"></img>
    <img id ="twitter" src="logos/TwitterIcon.png"></img>
    <img id ="googleplus" src="logos/GooglePlusIcon.png"></img>    
   </div>
   <p id="bkrwebsite">www.bkr.com</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">



/*function updateResult() {
  var r = results,
      rt = $('#result');
  if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
    rt.text('All Yes');
  } else if ((!r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (!r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
    rt.text('All No');
  } else {
    rt.text('We have a mixed response');
  }
}*/
var results = {};

function updateResult() {
 
 var r = results,
   rt = $('#result');


 if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 }   

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 }   

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 }

 <!-- YELLOW -->

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('yellow').addClass('yellow');
 }

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('yellow').addClass('yelllow');
 }  

 <!-- RED -->

 <!--else if (!r.quizquestionone) {-->
 <!--rt.text('Based on your responses, it’s not clear whether you qualify for a U-Visa. Please schedule a consultation with an experienced immigration attorney. She will collect more information about your specific circumstances and determine whether a U Visa is a realistic possibility or if other immigration benefits might serve you better. The cost of the consultation is only $100 and will be applied to the cost of any legal work performed on your behalf. You may call our office at (317) 571-3600 or fill out the following form to begin.  ').addClass('red');-->
 <!--}-->

 <!--else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!quizquestionfour)) {-->
 <!--rt.text('Based on your responses, it’s not clear whether you qualify for a U-Visa. Please schedule a consultation with an experienced immigration attorney. She will collect more information about your specific circumstances and determine whether a U Visa is a realistic possibility or if other immigration benefits might serve you better. The cost of the consultation is only $100 and will be applied to the cost of any legal work performed on your behalf. You may call our office at (317) 571-3600 or fill out the following form to begin.  ').addClass('red');-->
 <!--}-->
 else{
  rt.text('red').addClass('red');
 }
}

$(function result () {
  $('body').on('click', '[name]', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        page = $this.closest('.page'),
        next_page = $(page.next());
    results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
    page.removeClass('active');
    next_page.addClass('active');
    if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
  });
});
  
</script>
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a **minimal** [mcve] which is sufficient to duplicate the problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `onclick=result()` from submit button. And handle events from radio and submit buttons like this:

```
$('.quiz-questions input[type=radio], input[type=submit]').click(function (){
    var $this = $(this),
        page = $this.closest('.page'),
        next_page = $(page.next());
    results[$this.attr('name')] = ($(this).val() === 'yes');
    page.removeClass('active');
    next_page.addClass('active');
    if (next_page.hasClass('result')) updateResult();
});
```

Comment: doing that, it wont run the questions. I am unable to go through the questions.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I dont understand it correctly, What do you mean by moving it out of JQuery?

Comment: How will this redirect my question to the next screen though ? After the submit button I have a page that it should redirect too. If you could please explain that to me.

Comment: I didn't see there was a last page. I updated the code. Check once. https://jsbin.com/xilelecela/

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: great work @sam, needed to understand the purpose of the function.

Comment: @Mani no problem. Updated the code and explanation above. May be if you find this useful, you can **up** my answer above. :)

Answer (score 1):

> `if` clause inside a `.click` function (*i.e your **result()** funtion*) is not required.

Your function will be like:

```
$('.quiz-questions input[type=radio], input[type=submit]').click(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this),
        page = $this.closest('.page'),
        next_page = $(page.next());
    results[$this.attr('name')] = ($(this).val() === 'yes');
    page.removeClass('active');
    next_page.addClass('active');
    updateResult();
});
```

Run below code snippet:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
}
header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: 650px;
    margin-right: 650px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 5px;
}

div#main-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 467px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 30px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div#get-justice {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
div#get-justice p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    padding: 40px 40px 4px 40px;
    font-size: 28px;
}
div#get-justice button {
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding: 20px 37px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
h3 {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    font-size: 33px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
div#first-question {
   text-align: center;
}

ul {
    columns: 2;
    background: #EFDFBC;
 text-align: -webkit-left;
}
li {
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 0px 3px 37px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
input#quiz-question-one-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-one-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#oneYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#oneNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-two-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-two-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
label#twoYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#twoNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
input#quiz-question-three-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-three-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#threeYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}


/*label#threeYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#threeNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-four-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-four-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fourYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fourYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fourNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/
input#quiz-question-five-yes {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}
input#quiz-question-five-no {
    display: none;
    margin: 11px;
}

label#fiveYes {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 208px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -197px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*
label#fiveYes {
    display: inherit;
    margin: 13px 360px 0px 195px;
    padding: 8px 73px 8px 22px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}
label#fiveNo {
    display: inherit;
    margin: -54px 296px 0px 300px;
    padding: 12px 66px 5px 18px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-color: #ddd;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.clientinfo{
 height:445px;
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 1px 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 70px;
}

button {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
}

button#start {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 25px 35px 20px 25px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin-top: -272px;
    margin-right: 68px;
}

hr {
    width: 165px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}

div#disclaimer {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 27px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div#questionOneBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionTwoBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionThreeBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFourBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
div#questionFiveBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
h1 {
    /* padding: 20px 4px 20px; */
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
/*
h1 {
    //background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 20px 4px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
*/

h1#disclaimerHeader {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    /* padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px; */
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    background-color: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 20px;
}

div#disc-container {
    width: 450px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    padding: 10px 10px 14px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #bf2e1a;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

a#disclaimerLink {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*.hideHeader{
 display:none;
}*/

p#greenText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: green;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p#yellowText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: yellow;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}
p##bf2e1aText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 300px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

div#questionHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 163px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

/*div#resultHeader {
    margin-top: 163px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

div#resultHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}*/

div#resultHeader {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    width: 1170px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

div#quizResult {
    font-size: 20px;
    /* width: 650px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

div#allResult {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -350px;
    margin-right: -350px;
    /* background: #EFDFBC; */
}

div#leftResult {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    width: 610px;
}

div#result {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    height: 634px;
    font-size: 24.5px;
    width: 450px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    padding: 88px 45px 0px 70px;
    //font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr#eligibleHr {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 57px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 182px;
}

div#calenderToolSideText {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    /* width: 300px; */
    margin-left: 551px;
    margin-bottom: -18px;
    margin-top: -334px;
    padding: 0px 68px 0px 0px;
}

div#rightSide {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    margin-left: 480px;
    margin-top: -659px;
    height: 634px;
    width: 800px;
}

div#rightSide h1 {

    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    padding: 18px 10px 10px 10px;
}

hr#consultationHR {
    width: 595px;
    margin-right: 77px;
    margin-top: -29px;
}

div#calenderTool {
    background: blue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 330px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 148px;
}

hr#endingHR {
    width: 495px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    width: 597px;
    margin-right: 76px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

h3#shareQuiz {
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: -9px;
}

p#rightsidePara {
    margin-left: 131px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
 padding: 1px 0px 0px 20px;
}

p#rightsideParaTwo {
    margin-left: 136px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
}

h1#eligibleHeader {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
    color: #bf2e1a;
}

div#images {
    margin-left: 550px;
    margin-top: -85px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
p#bkrwebsite {
    margin-left: 550px;
    color: #bf2e1a;
}

h3#clientHeader {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bf2e1a;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    /* height: 400px; */
}

hr#clienFormHr {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

div#clientForm {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    margin-top: 33px;
    margin-left: 82px;
}


div#clientInfoBody {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    width: 425px;
    height: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input#client-info-submit {
    display: inline-block;
    /* margin: 85px; */
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #bf2e1a;
    /* border-color: #ddd; */
    font-size: 33px;
    text-align: center;
}

div#clienQuestionHeader {
    height: 140px;
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-top: 163px;
    font-size: 28px;
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: 113px;
    margin-right: 110px;
}


input#clientName {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 10px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

input#clientEmail {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

input#clientPhone {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 80px 5px 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

div#clientNameDiv {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

div#clientEmailDiv {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

div#clientPhoneDiv {
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

label#clientNameLabel {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 24px;
}

label#clientEmailLabel {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 24px;
}

label#clientPhoneLabel {
    background: #EFDFBC;
    font-size: 24px;
}


.verticalLine {
    width: 2px;
    height: 570px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 591px;
    margin-top: -615px;
}


.bkr-header{
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 445px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.visible2 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 165px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visible4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 195px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}

.visibleHeader {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}

.page {
 display: none;
}

.page.active {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
}

.green{
 color:green;
}

.yellow{
 color:yellow;
}

.red{
 color:red;
}


.questions {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 444px;
    background: #EFDFBC;
}
.questions-header {
    color: #EFDFBC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EFDFBC;
    top: 153px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    /* margin-top: 163px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    border-width: 10px;
}
.quiz-questions {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
 <title>Questions</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class = "quiz-questions">
 <div id="first-question" class="page active">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 1 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionOneBody">
  <h3>Questoin 1</h3>
  <ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
  </ul>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-yes" id="oneYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionone" id="quiz-question-one-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-one-no" id="oneNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="second-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 2 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionTwoBody">
   <h3>Question 2</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-yes" id="twoYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestiontwo" id="quiz-question-two-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-two-no" id="twoNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="third-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 3 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionThreeBody">
   <h3>Question 3 </h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-yes" id="threeYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionthree" id="quiz-question-three-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-three-no" id="threeNo">No</label>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fourth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 4 of 5</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFourBody">
   <h3>Question 4</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-yes" id="fourYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfour" id="quiz-question-four-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-four-no" id="fourNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="fifth-question" class="page">
  <div id="questionHeader">
   <h1> Question 5 of 5 </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="questionFiveBody">
   <h3>Question 5</h3>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-yes" value="yes" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-yes" id="fiveYes">Yes</label>
   <input type="radio" name="quizquestionfive" id="quiz-question-five-no" value="no" />
   <label for="quiz-question-five-no" id="fiveNo">No</label>  
  </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="client-info" class="page">
  <div id="clienQuestionHeader">
   <h1> Almost There </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="clientInfoBody">
   <h3 id="clientHeader">Input you contact information to see your eligibility</h3>
   <div id="clientForm">
    <label id="clientNameLabel" > Name : </label> 
    <div id="clientNameDiv">
     <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientName"/>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label id="clientEmailLabel"> Email: </label> 
    <div id="clientEmailDiv">
     <input type="text" name="clientemail" id="clientEmail" />
    </div>    
    <br>
    <label id="clientPhoneLabel"> Phone: </label> 
    <div id="clientPhoneDiv">
     <input type="text" name="clientphone" id="clientPhone"/>
    </div>      
    
    <br>
    <hr id="clienFormHr">
    <input type="submit" name="clientinformation" id="client-info-submit" />
    <!--<label for="client-info-submit" id="clientInfoLabel">No</label> -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  

<div class="page result">
 <div id="allResult">
  <div id="resultHeader">
   <h1> Congratulations </h1>
  </div>
  <h1 id="eligibleHeader"> You might be eligible. </h1>
  <hr id="eligibleHr">
  <div id="result">
  </div>
  <!-- Vertical Line -->
  <div class="verticalLine">
  </div>
  <!-- Vertical Line End -->
  <div id="rightSide">
   <h1>Schedule your free consultation now.</h1>
   <hr id="consultationHR">
   <div id="calenderTool">
   </div>
   <div id="calenderToolSideText">
    <p>Use this calender to schedule your appointment,
    or call our office to have someone do it for you.
    </p>
    <p>Because you pre-qualify, the consultation is free.</p>
    <br>
    <p>(317) 571-3600</p>
    <p>M - F, 8:30 am - 5:00 pm </p> 
   </div>
   <hr id="endingHR">
   <h3 id="shareQuiz"> Share the quiz </h3>
   <p id="rightsidePara"> Your friends won't see your results,</p>
   <p id="rightsideParaTwo">just alink to take it themselves. </p>
   <div id="images">
    <img id ="facebook" src="logos/FacebookIcon.png"></img>
    <img id ="twitter" src="logos/TwitterIcon.png"></img>
    <img id ="googleplus" src="logos/GooglePlusIcon.png"></img>    
   </div>
   <p id="bkrwebsite">www.bkr.com</p>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

 
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">



/*function updateResult() {
  var r = results,
      rt = $('#result');
  if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
    rt.text('All Yes');
  } else if ((!r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (!r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
    rt.text('All No');
  } else {
    rt.text('We have a mixed response');
  }
}*/
var results = {};

function updateResult() {
 
 var r = results,
   rt = $('#result');


 if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 }   

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 } 

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 }   

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (r.quizquestiontwo) && (r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('green').addClass('green');
 }

 <!-- YELLOW -->

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('yellow').addClass('yellow');
 }

 else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!r.quizquestiontwo) && (!r.quizquestionthree) && (r.quizquestionfour) && (!r.quizquestionfive)) {
  rt.text('yellow').addClass('yelllow');
 }  

 <!-- RED -->

 <!--else if (!r.quizquestionone) {-->
 <!--rt.text('Based on your responses, it’s not clear whether you qualify for a U-Visa. Please schedule a consultation with an experienced immigration attorney. She will collect more information about your specific circumstances and determine whether a U Visa is a realistic possibility or if other immigration benefits might serve you better. The cost of the consultation is only $100 and will be applied to the cost of any legal work performed on your behalf. You may call our office at (317) 571-3600 or fill out the following form to begin.  ').addClass('red');-->
 <!--}-->

 <!--else if ((r.quizquestionone) && (!quizquestionfour)) {-->
 <!--rt.text('Based on your responses, it’s not clear whether you qualify for a U-Visa. Please schedule a consultation with an experienced immigration attorney. She will collect more information about your specific circumstances and determine whether a U Visa is a realistic possibility or if other immigration benefits might serve you better. The cost of the consultation is only $100 and will be applied to the cost of any legal work performed on your behalf. You may call our office at (317) 571-3600 or fill out the following form to begin.  ').addClass('red');-->
 <!--}-->
 else{
  rt.text('red').addClass('red');
 }
}

 $('.quiz-questions input[type=radio], input[type=submit]').click(function (){
    var $this = $(this),
        page = $this.closest('.page'),
        next_page = $(page.next());
      results[$this.attr('name')] = $(this).val() === 'yes';
      page.removeClass('active');
      next_page.addClass('active');
         updateResult();
  });
  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I can surely try to debug the error but I doubt with my current level of JS, I'll be able to.

Comment: ohk, nice question though!

Comment: I would love to know your solution though. It just helps to me to know about different ways of doing the same thing. Thanks again

Comment: @Mani, check this solution, without **IF**, as it is there in another answer.